# How to style a Button element in Android UI?

Tags: android, xml, button

My button looks like this"

[image: Current State]

How can i make a simple button same as this

[image: Desired state]

and this is sample of my xml code:

```
<Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="MatchCenter"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/football"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:background="@drawable/my_button"
                android:id="@+id/MatchCenter"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                />
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, unfortunately your question does not demonstrate any attempt of prior research. In order to get a good response, it is advised you should show evidence you have attempted to solve the problem, either in code or otherwise, before asking a question. 

StackOverflow is not a free code generator. Please seek assistance elsewhere should you require free source code.

Comment: In other words, this site requires that you have to show what you have tried before asking what do you want!

Comment: My first photo shows that i'm tried to do something like that and i surely make searches but without result.

Comment: You'll need to explain exactly what changes you're trying to make. Are you having trouble with the border? what about the colours - they're quite different? For a question on SO to receive a good response you're going to have to be as precise as possible, so that we don't have to spend a great deal of time trying to figure these out and (potentially) wasting time on things you don't care about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a 9-patch as your background https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html